# minimum stop to get to destination

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

```
Class GasStation {
    int distanceToDestination;
    int availableGas;
}
```

given three parameterd **g** represents vehicle initial gas amount, **d** represents distance to destination. and a list of gasStations where for each gasStation the variable is  **distanceToDestination** and the second is availableGas of that station. How to compute minimum stop to get to destination?

```
g = 10 gallon,
d = 20 miles,
list of GasStation:
gasStations = [[15, 1], [14,10], [12,12]].
```

Edit: there is no capacity limit.

Comment: 1.  You are going to need to know the fuel economy of the vehicle.  2.  This sounds like a twist on the salesman problem.

Comment: You are missing required information.  You have supplied g=gas capacity which means the maximimum amount of fuel you can use in the vehicle.  What is the initial amount of gas? what is the distance-to-fuel ratio?

Comment: Why did you tag "greedy"? Do you expect only greedy algorithm solutions?

Comment: @nurdyguy Which "salesman problem" are you referring to? It's certainly not anything like the Traveling Salesman Problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't mentioned it I am going to assume you need `k` gallons of gas to travel `1` mile. This can be solved by DP if total capacity isn't too big. I have outlined a solution using recursion with memoization.

```
gasStations  = [list of GasStations]
sort gasStations  by decreasing value of distanceToDestination if its not already sorted
k : gas required to travel 1 mile
maxNumberOfGasStation : maximum gas stations possible
maxPossibleCapacity : maximum gas that might be required for a trip
memo = [maxNumberOfGasStation][maxPossibleCapacity] filled up with -1

int f(idx, currentGas) {
    if (G[idx].distanceToDestination * k <= current_gas) {
        // You can reach destination using the gas you have left without filling any more
        return 0
    }
    if(idx == gasStations.length - 1) {
        // last station
        if (G[idx].distanceToDestination * k > current_gas + G[idx].availableGas) {
            // You cannot reach destination even if you fill up here
            return INT_MAX
        } else{
            return 1;
        }
    }   
    if(memo[idx][currentGas] != -1) return memo[idx][currentGas];

    // option 1: stop at this station
    int distBetweenStation = G[idx].distanceToDestination - G[idx+1].distanceToDestination
    int r1 = 1 + f(idx+1, min(currentGas + G[idx].availableGas, maxPossibleCapacity) - distBetweenStation * k)

    // option 2: don't stop at this station
    int r2 = f(idx+1, currentGas - distBetweenStation * k)

    // take minimum
    int r = min(r1, r2)

    memo[idx][currentGas] = r
    return r;
}
```

To get the answer call `f(0, g - (d - gasStations[0].distanceToDestination) * k)`. Time complexity is `O(maxNumberOfGasStation  * maxPossibleCapacity)`. If there is a `capicity` limit you can simply replace `maxPossibleCapacity` with it.